# Loading "..." loop, with changing text every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6A7xh/1/

The purpose of this script is to output

**Loading.**

[1 second delay] ->

**Loading..**

[1 second delay] ->

**Loading...**

[1 second delay] ->

**Painting Mona Lisa.**

[1 second delay] ->

**Painting Mona Lisa..**

[ and so on ]

---

So here's the stuff:

```
 loadList = [
    "Loading the good stuff",
    "Painting Mona Lisa",
    "Just a second longer",
    "Or not",
    "Oh! We forgot to plug it in",
    "That's better",
    "Well",
    "Maybe not",
    "Wondering why",
    "your internet is so slow",
    "Still",
    "Loading",
];


var i = 0;
var x = 0;

function loadTrans(x){
        //if (!$(window).ready){
            $(".intro > p").text(loadList[x]);
            playTrans();
        //}
}

function playTrans(){
    currentText = $(".intro > p").text();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".intro > p").text( currentText + ".");
        if(i == 3){
            x++;
            loadTrans(x);
        }
        i++;
        if(i < 4){
            playTrans();
            i = 0;
        }

    },1000);
}

loadTrans();
```

I think what I'm trying to do is clear, but it appears my method is failing so far. Right now, the script is adding the periods in a never ending loop, and the transitions aren't happening every third loop.

**What am I doing wrong here? Does anyone know a way I could do this more neatly?**

Note: I originally did this with a for loop, but setTimeout obviously fails in that situation.

Comment: you can `playTrans` botn in `playTrans` and in `loadTrans`

Comment: Why does setTimeout fail?

Comment: @Grundy can you elaborate a little? The way I'm seeing it, I set it up so that it would playTrans while i < 4 but on i == 3, loadTrans would happen after which I would need to playTrans in loadTrans to keep the loop going.

Comment: @tewathia it fails because setTimeout is called immediately and the loop will call 3 setTimeouts very fast, so what you'll see is a 3 second delay then a jump where all three events occur.

Comment: You can set the setTimeout interval to `1000*i` with i++ every time and reset i every third time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can do this](http://jsfiddle.net/6A7xh/10/). You can put this in a function, and the timer in a variable. When your resources are all loaded, you can use `clearInterval` to clear the timer.

```
 var i = 0;
 var textarea = $('.intro p');

 var loadTimer = setInterval(function () {
     if (i % 4 === 0) textarea.text(loadList[i / 4]); //change text after 3 steps
     else textarea.text(textarea.text() + '.');       //add period
     ((i / 4) < loadList.length) ? i++ : i = 0;       //back to start
 }, 500);
```

Comment: This looks good, very neat, efficient too, and what's the best way to cut off the setInterval function if it goes beyond the array? Is there a clearInterval?

Comment: @jt0dd Yup, there is a `clearInterval`. Just added it in the answer.

Comment: I would say that this is possibly the best way to execute this simple loading function in Javascript. I'm sure many others will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

One problem :

```
i++;
if (i < 4) { 
    i = 0; // i : 0, 1, 0, 1...
}
```

Comment: I've never actually used clearTimeout. But I think I see what that does here.. If TimeOut stays set.. erm. Hrm.

Comment: @jt0dd Sorry, I've mixed up `setInterval` and `setTimeout`... ^^'